# Moved magento2 site now site missing pub/static in url

Tags: magento2

I moved a magento2 website to a new server and changed the url (so I can have a development version of the website.

Now I did the upgrade, recompile and even redeploy'ed the site since its in production mode but when I go to the site all the image/css urls are missing the pub/static part of the url and I dont know why??

Comment: check .htaccess file in root directory.

Comment: I see i was missing the .htaccess file.

Comment: Means now it is working fine issue was due to .htaccess right?

Comment: facing same problem

Comment: My issue ended up being that I was missing a .htaccess file in the magento root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this very same issue with Nginx.  It actually turned out that the developer who duplicated the database created an entry for

web/unsecure/base_static_url
web/secure/base_static_url
web/unsecure/base_media_url
web/secure/base_media_url

Setting those to NULL in core_config_data solved the problem.

Hope that helps.